# Ducted Fan vs Open Propeller Efficiency

Tags: aircraft-design, propeller

If we are talking about a slow flying aircraft with subsonic propeller tips, will adding a shroud increase efficiency, all else being the same?(ignoring the friction drag)

Comment: By ignoring the friction drag you remove the basis for a fair comparison. A friction-less shroud will help to increase thrust, but not efficiency.

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit? Why doesn't the efficiency increase, is it because of the added weight?

Comment: No, because of higher induced losses. The minimum is reached with fairly lightly loaded tips. Adding a duct will allow to load the tips more, so more thrust is generated, but disproportionally higher torque is required to keep the prop spinning.